# Angular Material mat-select item with id and pass to another input box

Tags: angular-material

[image]

```
<mat-select formControlName="employeeid" [(ngModel)]="selected" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)" >
                <input style=" width: -webkit-fill-available; margin-bottom: 10px; height: 30px;" placeholder="Search & Select"/>
                <div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto">
                  <mat-option>Select Employee</mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of employeeDropdown" [value]="item.employeeid">{{ item.firstname }}</mat-option>
                </div>
              </mat-select>            
            </mat-form-field>


<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="1 1 calc(50% - 10px)" fxFlex.lt-md="1 1 calc(30% - 10px)"
              fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="from-color">
              <mat-label class="label-padding">Employee Details</mat-label>
              <input class="label-padding" type="text" matInput placeholder="Employee Details"
                  formControlName="firstname" [value]="selected" required/>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Showing ID on input box but I want the Employee Name to show on input box.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While selecting a drop down list only Item name will pass to Input box not id in angular. If I select another item  the input box will also show the selected item. Whatever I select on drop down it will go to input box.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Category } from '../models/category';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
const products: Product[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Grapes' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Apples' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Lemons' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Bananas' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Mangoes' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Beets' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Cabbage' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Carrot' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Onions' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Peanuts' },
  { id: 11, name: 'Walnuts' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Almonds' }
];
​
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
​
  constructor() { }
​  
​
  GetProductNameById(productId) {
    return products.filter(product => product.id == productId);
  }
}

<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onSelection()">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let pro of proNames" [value]="pro.id">{{pro.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label class="label-padding">Name</mat-label>
  <input class="label-padding" type="text" matInput placeholder="Name"
                  formControlName="name"/>
</mat-form-field>

onSelection() {
console.log(this.selected); 
this.nameService.GetProductNameById(this.selected).subscribe((data) => {
      if(data){        
        let proName = data.apiData.name;
        this.name?.patchValue(proName );
        console.log(data.apiData.name);
      }
  }`
```